# python pandas give comma separated values into columns with "title"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have some comma-separated data in the same column and I wish to separate each value into different columns.

```
0          13.4119837, 42.082885, 13.4119837, 42.082885
1        11.6285463, 42.4193742, 11.6285463, 42.4193742
2            -3.606772, 39.460299, -3.606772, 39.460299
3            -0.515639, 38.988847, -0.515639, 38.988847
4            -2.403309, 37.241792, -2.403309, 37.241792
```

I have done separation using below

```
data['column_name'].str.split(",", n = 3, expand = True)
```

and the output I got is

```
     0           1           2           3
0   13.4119837  42.082885   13.4119837  42.082885
1   11.6285463  42.4193742  11.6285463  42.4193742
2   -3.606772   39.460299   -3.606772   39.460299
3   -0.515639   38.988847   -0.515639   38.988847
4   -2.403309   37.241792   -2.403309   37.241792
```

but I need something like below (has to give some titles for each column)

```
    minLat      maxLat       minLong     maxLong
0   13.4119837  42.082885   13.4119837  42.082885
1   11.6285463  42.4193742  11.6285463  42.4193742
2   -3.606772   39.460299   -3.606772   39.460299
3   -0.515639   38.988847   -0.515639   38.988847
4   -2.403309   37.241792   -2.403309   37.241792
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html):

```
data = data['column_name'].str.split(",", n = 3, expand = True)
data.columns = ['minLat', 'maxLat', 'minLong', 'maxLong']
```